# Export Report, excluding column

Tags: reporting-services, export, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I created a report (via Report Builder 3.0), which I set to Group on specific Column.
When Exporting to Excel, I set up the report to have each Group on different Sheet, with the name of each Sheet matching the value of the Group.

My question is - how do I exclude the Grouped column from being added as a column on the Excel sheets.
I obviously need to still have the same functionality, but don't need the actual column to show up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do it with parameters.

   Create a Dataset
   SELECT "0" AS Value, "View" as Label
   union all
   SELECT "1" AS Value, "Print" as Label

then in *"Column Visibility..."*

Click "Show or Hide based on an Expression"

Then create an expression to utilise the parameter values.

2. In Code

Select the header of the column you want to hide, right-click and select *"Column Visibility…"*. In the dialog that pops up, select “Show or hide based on an expression”.

Enter this as an expression:

```
=Iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", True, False)
```

Comment: Problem is that the Grouped column does not have a Column Visibility option - grayed out...
Any way to bypass this limitation?

Comment: is the column you are hiding part of a column group?

Comment: The Column I am trying to hide in the Excel output file is the one I setup the Group.

Comment: Will explain using an example :)

Lets say I have a report that gives table output with list of 6 people, that includes their Name and Country:
Germany - John, Mary
England - Peter, Sam
US - Natalie, George

The Report will have 2 columns - 1 with the group per Country, and the 2nd with the Names.

Exporting to Excel like I setup will have
 A. 3 Sheets, the name of each with the name of the Country
 B. Each will have the Country column and Name.

So what I want is for point A to still happen the same, but on point B to only have the Name column...

Comment: @NeilNorris Does this approach actually work for you? I've tried it on 2008R2 and 2016 and it has never worked. It doesn't work when I export from Report Builder or from the Report Server. I'm tempted to say pic or it didn't happen.

Comment: I listed two ways that have worked for me in the past, as for a pic - you can ask for one but due to the nature of the data I work with, I am not allowed to publish it.